# Travis exit with 65 code and fails to create a bundle instance

Tags: ios, continuous-integration, travis-ci, xcodebuild

Started learning how to integrate continuous integration (CI) using Travis platform for a personal project "*Building a simple framework for iOS Development on Xcode*". And, after a successful run creating a .travis.yml file with a set of configurations somehow I got caught up with a bunch of errors that I'm not quite familiar with.

Here's a snapshot of the travis.yml file

```
language: swift

os: osx

osx_image: xcode10.2

script:
  - set -o pipefail && xcodebuild -project SWToaster.xcodeproj -scheme SWToaster -configuration Debug -destination 'platform=iOS Simulator,OS=12.0,name=iPhone XR' ONLY_ACTIVE_ARCH=YES  
  - set -o pipefail && xcodebuild test-without-building -enableCodeCoverage YES -scheme SWToasterTests -destination 'platform=iOS Simulator,OS=12.0,name=iPhone XR' ONLY_ACTIVE_ARCH=YES
```

And here is a snapshot of error messages:

[image: Error messages response from Travis CI]

Anyone sort of help will be appreciated

Answer (score 0):

Resolved the issue by making sure the following requirements are met

1. Listed supported iOS Simulator SDK on Travis
2. Checked supported Xcode version on Travis

Then updated a ***.travis.yml*** config file as follows.

```
language: swift

os: osx
osx_image: xcode10.2

env:
  matrix: 
    - TEST_SDK=iphonesimulator12.2 OS=12.2 NAME='iPhone 7' 

script:
  - set -o pipefail && xcodebuild -version
  - set -o pipefail && xcodebuild -showsdks 
  - set -o pipefail && xcodebuild -project SWToaster.xcodeproj -scheme SWToaster -configuration Debug -destination "platform=iOS Simulator,OS=12.0,name=iPhone XR" ONLY_ACTIVE_ARCH=YES
  - set -o pipefail && xcodebuild test -enableCodeCoverage YES -project SWToaster.xcodeproj -scheme SWToaster -sdk $TEST_SDK -destination "platform=iOS Simulator,OS=$OS,name=$NAME" ONLY_ACTIVE_ARCH=YES
```